# Using Regexp match to access array/object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have:

```
 window.page="home";
 document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML=
      "hello.com | $page".replace(/\$([^\s]*)/g,window["$1"]);
```

The idea is to get:

```
 <title>hello.com | home</title>
```

But I instead get:

```
 <title>hello.com | undefined</title>
```

When I do the following:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML=
      "hello.com | $page".replace(/\$([^\s]*)/g,"$1");
```

I get:

```
 <title>hello.com | page</title>
```

This is because the function is taking `"$1"` as an argument with which to map its output. I'm wondering if there is a way to use the capture group to access an array/object?

Comment: Use a callback, `.replace(/\$(\S*)/g, function($0,$1) {return window[$1];})`

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use  a backreference that can only be used a part of the *string replacement pattern* as an argument. You need to use a [replace callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for that.

Use

```
.replace(/\$(\S*)/g, function($0,$1) {return window[$1];})
```

Note that `\S` (a non-whitespace) is shorter than `[^\s]` (not a whitespace).

In `function($0,$1)`, the `$0` stands for the whole match, while `$1` stands for the Group 1 contents.